# Collect Static creating a clone of my static files folder Django

Tags: python, django

I need to refresh a js file in my static files folder, however whenever I run python manage.py collectstatic, a clone of my static files folder is created in a diffrent part of the project, and the js file is still not updated. I tried changing the STATIC_ROOT variable in the settings.py file to the actual location of my static folder, but it doesn't seem to refresh because the collectstatic warning message in the console says its going to be saved in a completely different location.

The Structure of my project is

```
resume_V6-test
    -resume
        -home
            -static (actual location)
        
        -resume
            -settings.py
        -store
        -staticfiles (clone of the static folder)
        -users
```

and my settings.py is

```
# Commented out the location it was before I tried fixing the error

#STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    #os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    #'/resume_V6-test/resume/home/static',
#]


#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'home/static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

And the error message is

```
 python manage.py collectstatic

You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings:

    C:\resume_V6-test\resume\staticfiles

This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

STATIC_ROOT is the output destination for the static file. E.g. this is where collectstatic collects all the static files to (read here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/)

The default is to collect all static files from all apps from /static directory of each app.

If you want extra location to collect from, you can use the STATICFILES_DIRS settings. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS)